# How to fix Code Analysis warning CS8605 when using foreach with Enum.GetValues()?

Tags: c#, code-analysis, nullable-reference-types

Consider the following .Net Core 3.1 code:

```
using System;

namespace CoreConsoleA
{
    public static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // Warning CS8605, Unboxing a possibly null value:
            foreach (MyEnum enumValue in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(enumValue);
            }
        }
    }

    enum MyEnum { Zero, One, Two };
}
```

With Code Analysis and nullable checking turned on, the code above elicits "Warning CS8605 Unboxing a possibly null value."

I can suppress the warning using "#pragma warning disable CS8605".

I can also write the code like so:

```
foreach (MyEnum? enumValue in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)))
{
    Console.WriteLine(enumValue!.Value);
}
```

but that seems a bit weird, given that `Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))` can't possibly return any nulls.

Is there a better way to address this issue?

Comment: You may add `OfType<MyEnum>()` or `Cast<MyEnum>()` after `GetValues`. The issue may be caused by the fact, that [`GetValue`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Array.CoreCLR.cs,251c99c8419d33d4,references) method of `Array` returns an `object?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Answering my own question, since I just realised what I should be doing!)

You can just cast the return value of `Enum.GetValues()` to the correct type, like so:

```
foreach (var enumValue in (MyEnum[]) Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)))
{
    Console.WriteLine(enumValue);
}
```

Comment: `foreach (var enumValue in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)) as MyEnum[])` seems a bit more readable. Poking around looking into this I found this library that looks pretty interesting and may be of help. https://github.com/xin9le/FastEnum

Comment: or `foreach (MyEnum enumValue in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<MyEnum>())`

Comment: @asawyer That still gives a warning (CS8602)

Comment: @GuruStron That would create additional overhead, involving reflection for each element - much better to just do a single cast which will involve only one reflection check (to see if the array itself is castable, rather than for each element of the array)

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes, but i would say that the difference is not that big in most cases (compared to all other stuff). Benchmarking enum with 65 values gave me difference  0.5µs.

Comment: @GuruStron Even so, I find the cast more readable, and it more accurately describes what is happening (i.e. the returned value really IS an array of the enum type, rather than being some collection where the items need to be converted one-by-one).